# Magento 2 Limit Product quantity per customer

Tags: magento2, product, cart, sales

In my magento store there are virtual subscription products which come as trials. I need to set maximum 1 product which is allowed to purchase by a customer. Does any one knows what is the programmatic way to do this ?

Comment: This will useful for your requirement exactly https://marketplace.magento.com/rage-sales-limiter.html there is configuration at the product creation to limit the product of being purchased.
Thanks

Comment: @GPrathap yes. it looks like match my requirement. currently magento marketplace is under some maintenance.  Will let you know about the results after I try the extension you mentioned about.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool, you're welcome